# Counting sequential rows with the same / missing value

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, sequence

I have a time series dataset containing different sensor measurements. The sensors software has some bugs, resulting in missing measurements. I added the missing measurement times, resulting in NAs in the "value" column. The dataset looks as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(time_id = 1:10, value = c(-1.80603125680195, -0.582075924689333, 
                                              NA, NA, -0.162309523556819, NA, NA, NA, 1.6059096288573, NA), 
                    is_missing = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                                   TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                   ), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
df
```

I want to group sequential rows with numeric vs missing values and at the same time count the number of sequential rows in each group. The result should look like this:

```
df %>% mutate(group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6),
              seq_NA = c(1:2, 1:2, 1, 1:3, 1, 1))
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another idea. Here we use `is.na()` to capture the NAs and change group whenever a non-NA appears, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(is.na(value)) != 0))) %>% 
 mutate(seq_NA = seq(n()))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 5
> # Groups:   grp [6]
>    time_id  value is_missing   grp seq_NA
>      <int>  <dbl> <lgl>      <dbl>  <int>
>  1       1 -1.81  FALSE          1      1
>  2       2 -0.582 FALSE          1      2
>  3       3 NA     TRUE           2      1
>  4       4 NA     TRUE           2      2
>  5       5 -0.162 FALSE          3      1
>  6       6 NA     TRUE           4      1
>  7       7 NA     TRUE           4      2
>  8       8 NA     TRUE           4      3
>  9       9  1.61  FALSE          5      1
> 10      10 NA     TRUE           6      1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `ave()` + `rle()`

```
df$group <- with(df, rep(seq_along(z<-rle(is_missing)$lengths),z))
df$seq_NA <- with(df,ave(seq(nrow(df)),group,FUN = seq_along))
```

such that

```
> df
   time_id      value is_missing group seq_NA
1        1 -1.8060313      FALSE     1      1
2        2 -0.5820759      FALSE     1      2
3        3         NA       TRUE     2      1
4        4         NA       TRUE     2      2
5        5 -0.1623095      FALSE     3      1
6        6         NA       TRUE     4      1
7        7         NA       TRUE     4      2
8        8         NA       TRUE     4      3
9        9  1.6059096      FALSE     5      1
10      10         NA       TRUE     6      1
```

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to agree with OPs expected output